# jQuery magnific-popup submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

Is it possible to make an extra button on the jquery magnific-popup component, with the functionality to close the dialog?

I'm using the component to add a description to a photo, therefor I'll need a submit button that will add the description via ajax to the photo (this happens already) but the dialog isn't closing...

Comment: Code? Mention that magnific-popup is a plugin (maybe even a link)?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the doc closely you can do it like:

- $.magnificPopup.close(); // Close popup that is currently opened (shorthand)
- $('.element-with-popup').magnificPopup('close'); // Will closethe popup